# jQuery: How to get first value and last value on input text

Tags: jquery, html

I have no idea how to get last value on input text. I already get the first value, when input type is empty did not get value. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/17"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/18"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/18"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/19"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/19"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value=""><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value=""><br/>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $set = $('.date');
    var len = $set.length; 
    $set.each(function(index, element) {
        if (index === 0) {
            alert (this.value);
        }
    });     
});
```

Comment: where is your markup?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw i already edited my post

Comment: NOTE: It is not advised to have multiple input elements with the same `id`, especially when they are all inside a single form. I'm hoping that is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse your loop and start from the last.

```
var $set = $('.date');
var len = $set.length;
var firstVal = $($set[0]).val();
var lastVal = null;
for (var i = len - 1; i > 0; i--){
  if ($($set[i]).val()){
    lastVal = $($set[i]).val();
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [value!=''] to select only inputs with values. 
Then use first() and last() to get values from the first item and last item from the selected list.

```js
var $values = $(".date[value!='']");
$("#firstValue").html($values.first().val());
$("#lastValue").html($values.last().val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/17"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/18"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/18"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/19"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/19"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value=""><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value=""><br/>
<div>First value: <span id="firstValue"></span></div>
<div>Last value: <span id="lastValue"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! already worked but did not change when i put value in empty field

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how to get last value on input text. I already get the
>   first value, when input type is empty did not get value.

this should work.

```js
var result =  $("input[value!='']");
console.log(result.first().val());
console.log(result.last().val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/17"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/18"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/18"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/19"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value="6/19"><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value=""><br/>
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="date" id="date" value=""><br/>
```

Also, just as a side tip, don't use multiple `id` attributes that have the same value because that's invalid HTML. Rather, if you want to access multiple elements use the class attribute which you've already done.